# How to enable two texFields when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript

I have two text fields like so:

```
 <label for="origin2">
    <g:message code="api.origin2.label" default="2nd Origin" />
 </label>
 <g:textField  class="form-control" name="origin2" value="${apiInstance?.origin2}"/>

 <label for="destination2">
    <g:message code="api.destination2.label" default="2nd Destination" />
 </label>
 <g:textField class="form-control"  name="destination2" value="${apiInstance?.destination2}"/>
```

First question (I;m new to this), how do I initially disable these text fields?

Second question, I have a checkbox:

```
  <label for="multicity">
    <g:message code="api.multicity.label" default="Multi-City" />
  </label>
  <g:checkBox  id="multicity" onClick="toggle('multicity', 'origin2')" name="multicity" value="${apiInstance?.multicity}" checked="${false}" />
```

Ideally I'd like to have the above two text boxes suddenly appear if this checkbox is checked (true) but if that can't be done I just want to enable them.

How do I do this? All help vastly appreciated.

Comment: you can do all that stuff, yes. Have you done any research? You can find tutorials, documention, examples etc regarding JavaScript which will tell you how to handle the event of a checkbox being checked, how to enable/disable/show/hide/create/destroy elements such as textboxes. Do some basic research and make an attempt at your code, you'll learn a lot more that way than someone here just giving you a code sample which you might not really understand. If you get stuck after a time, post your attempt here and we can help you finish it off, and explain what to do so you understand better.

Comment: I have created an alternate solution using CSS for the problem you've stated. The benefit of using CSS vs. JavaScript is that it is generally safer and will work in the webbrowser even with JavaScript turned off. If you are interested in this, please reply to my comment, add the "CSS" tag, and edit your question with something like "Also interested in a CSS solution"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple just add readonly attr to your input field like this.

```
<input type="text" name="lname" readonly>
```

And then add your script e.g

```
  $("#checkbox").click(() => {
    $("#field1, #field2").removeAttr("readonly")
  })
```